# What's the principle of LOADDLL.EXE?

Tags: dll, reverse-engineering, entry-point

It can be used to run arbitary Dynamic Link Library in windows,

how can it possibly know the entry point of an arbitary dll?

Comment: @halfdan, SO's a place for questions to get answered, not for reputation whoring, right?  Why not just answer his question?

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on how much details you need. Basically, it comes down to this:

> *A DLL can optionally specify an entry-point function. If present, the system calls the entry-point function whenever a process or thread loads or unloads the DLL.*
>
> [...] *If you are providing your own entry-point, see the DllMain function. The name DllMain is a placeholder for a user-defined function. You must specify the actual name you use when you build your DLL.*

(Taken from the MSDN article [*Dynamic-Link Library Entry-Point Function*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682596%28VS.85%29.aspx).)

So basically, the entry point can be specified inside the DLL, and the operating system's DLL loader knows how to look this up.

Answer (score 0):

The `IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER` (part of the portable executable's header on Windows machines) contains an RVA of the `AddressOfEntryPoint` that is called by programs looking for an entry point to call (e.g., the loader).

More information on the `IMAGE_OPTIONAL_HEADER` can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680339(VS.85).aspx).  And [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc301805.aspx) paper is good for just general PE knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "run a DLL"? DLLs aren't normal programs, they are just a collection of functions. The entry point itself *usually* doesn't do much apart from initializing stuff required by other functions in the DLL. The entry point is automatically called when the DLL is loaded (you can use [`LoadLibrary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684175%28VS.85%29.aspx) to do this).

If you want to call a specific function after loading the DLL, you can use [`GetProcAddress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683212%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) to get a pointer to the function you want.